# Dictionary with key of string with different word order

Tags: python, dictionary, duplicates, set, key

I have a dictionary of strings as the key with different word order.
How can I remove duplicate keys (same words set with different order)?
The values are same for the same keys, so just need to select 1 out of them.

The simple idea was to use `set(words)` as the key, but dictionary does not allow a `set` as the key. Is there a nice and neat way to handle this?

```
my_dict={'Hello tom': 2, 'tom Hello': 2, 'I ate apple': 4, 'ate I apple': 4, 'apple ate I':4}
```

Result

```
my_dict_trimmed={'Hello tom': 2, 'I ate apple': 4}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any time you want to hash a set, use a `frozenset`.

```
output = dict()
for key, value in dictionary.iteritems():
    new_key = frozenset(key.split())
    if new_key not in output.keys():
         output[new_key] = value
```

Comment: the key in your output is the `frozenset(key.split()` transformed key, which may not match any key in the original dictionary - if that matters, depends on how to read *"How can I remove duplicate keys (same words set with different order)?"* - nothing about scrambling the one you keep

Answer (score 1):

Use `frozenset` which is immutable and hashable.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
my_dict={'Hello tom':2, 'tom Hello':2, 'I ate apple':4, 'ate I apple':4, 'apple ate I':4}

my_dict_trimmed = dict()

for k in my_dict:
    if sorted(k) in map(sorted, my_dict_trimmed):
        continue
    else:
        my_dict_trimmed[k] = my_dict[k]
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I see a problem or two

just using `sorted` fails on anagrams
its words that need to be sorted after splitting

```
my_dict={'Hello tom':2, 'tom Hello':2, 'I ate apple':4, 'ate I apple':4, 'apple ate I':4}

def MashedKey(k):
    return tuple(sorted(k.split()))

umsk = set([MashedKey(k) for k in my_dict.keys()]) # unique Mashed keys

umsk
Out[48]: {('Hello', 'tom'), ('I', 'apple', 'ate')}
```

then the key, value pairs have to be retrieved from my_dict through the same key 'mashing" function, here taking the 1st equality:

```
od = {}
for u in umsk:
    for k, v in my_dict.items():
        if MashedKey(k) == u:
            od.update({k: v})
            break

od
Out[50]: {'Hello tom': 2, 'apple ate I': 4}
```